# PHP abandons SQlite?

Tags: php, sqlite, pecl

> The SQLite extension is enabled by default as of PHP 5.0. Beginning
>   with PHP 5.4, the SQLite extension is available only via PECL.

Ok, I'm relatively new in PHP programming, and I was wondering what does this quoted information from official PHP site mean?

I wrote some applications that runs SQlite rather than MySQL database and I have serious concern if is it going to be deprecated from future versions of PHP.

What does it means "from now, only via PECL"?
I understand that SQlite *will be available* but doesn't that mean that:

1. **PHP team will pay at least less attention on future development of PHP/SQlite integration**
2. **we could expect web hosting providers that will miss installing SQlite extension, as it is not by default any more?**

Does someone have experience about what's happen when PHP "throw away" extension to PECL?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a discussion: Why do you insist using SQlite ? Consider using MySQL .

Comment: 1. Simplicity (not involving users to create db'sses, users for db'ses, granting permissions...) 2. Fast execution time (especially on shared hosting accounts)

Comment: for 2nd point, you're 50% correct. SQlite is fast only if you mainly use read queries ( SELECTs ). Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630/sqlite-vs-mysql

Comment: I have voted to close. This is a question you should be asking the PHP team. The answer to this question will not help anyone solve a programming problem, including you.

Comment: but the answer isn't an answer to the question. This is: `Q: based on <wrong assumption> what will happen?! A: <wrong assumption> is wrong!`. So while it is usefull to find out the assumption is wrong, the question itself isn't very usefull, nor is there an answer (which cannot exist as it was based on a wrong assumption)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but it looks to me like PHP is dropping support for the old [SQLite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php) extension in 5.4 in favour of the (newer and better) [SQLite3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php) extension.

> The SQLite3 extension is enabled by default as of PHP 5.3.0.

A major benefit of SQLite is how simple it is to setup—and having it as part of the PHP core is important to keeping it that way. I don't see that changing.

Comment: Thank you very much Jonathan. That's exactly what I missed - Sqlite2 was removed due to beginning with SQLite3.