# Fastest way to test a server for sqlite via a PHP file?

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm not sure if my server has sqlite on it, so I want to use a PDO object to test and see if the server supports sqlite.  I tried:

```
<?php
echo `sqlite3 -v`;
```

got the following error: `Warning: shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could just use [function_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) to check if sqlite functions are present, like this:

```
if (function_exists('sqlite_open')) {
   echo 'Sqlite PHP extension loaded';
}
```

For `SQLite3` the former won't work, so use this instead <sup>(courtesy of Prid's comment)</sup>:

```
if (class_exists('SQLite3')) {
   echo 'SQLite3 extension loaded';
}
```

Comment: Command line version: `php -r 'echo function_exists("sqlite_open") ? "yes" : "no";'`

Comment: If you are using PHP7 or up, use PDO instead. this seems to be outdated since newer than 5.4

Comment: **this won't work for SQLite3!** Use this instead: `if(class_exists('SQLite3')){`

Answer (score 8):

Or you can simply use :

```
if (extension_loaded('sqlite3')) {
    // Do things
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php

Answer (score 1):

It is disabled in your `php.ini`
You need to look for **shell_exec** in it, if you want to run shell-commands directly.

It might be under

```
disable_functions = ..., shell_exec, ...
```

Comment: Actually, I can't even SSH in.  It's a free webhost that I'm just using to test scripts out, remotely.  I don't think that I'm allowed to edit php.ini.

Comment: I don't think free-webhosts actually give you a way to modify php.ini.

Answer (score 1):

Is your provider is supporting sqlite3 then you can test it this way:

```
<?php

print_r(SQLite3::version());

?>
```

please also consult to the manual : https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php

Answer (score 0):

I've actually found a way to test this, now:

```
<?php
echo sqlite_libversion();
echo "<br>";
echo phpversion();
```

returns something like this:

```
2.8.17
5.2.17
```

Comment: If the sqlite extension is not present, your call to `sqlite_libversion` will generate a runtime php error, you would need to use `function_exists()` to prevent that.

Comment: @Nelson you could also use `function_exists('sqlite_libversion')`, but it is more typing, right? :)

Comment: If you are using PHP7 or up, use PDO instead. this seems to be outdated since newer than 5.4

Answer (score 0):

For **PHP 5.4.0 and up**, the accepted answer won't work as the old SQLite extension [was dropped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10620674/3705191).

Try this as an alternative:

```
if (class_exists('SQLite3')) {
   echo 'Sqlite PHP extension loaded';
}
```

or use [extension_loaded('sqlite3')](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28949863/3705191) instead.